# Erro causado pela quebra de linha no append

Tags: jquery, append

No jquery, se eu inserir o seguinte código, da erro ::

```
variavel.append('<div class="qualquer">
                    <div class="subdivs">
                        conteudo da subdiv
                    </div>
                    <div class="subdivs">
                        conteudo da subdiv
                    </div>
                </div>
                    ');
```

Porém se eu colocar o mesmo código sem quebra de linha, já não da mais erro ::

```
variavel.append('<div class="qualquer"><div class="subdivs">conteudo da subdiv</div><div class="subdivs">conteudo da subdiv</div></div>');
```

Minha duvida é

> Como evitar esse erro causado pela quebra de linha? Existe um "substituto" pro append para que eu possa inserir o código com quebra de linha?
>
> > OBS: Estou tentando aprender mais sobre o JQuery portanto desconheço os meios para realizar tal coisa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre devido as quebras de linhas que impedem a formação da `string`, que é o argumento aceito pelo `append()` do **jQuery**. Você pode resolver isso utilizando `\` no final de cada linha, nesse caso será necessário trocar suas aspas duplas (`"`) por simples (`'`) nos conteúdos internos conforme abaixo:

```
variavel.append("<div class='qualquer'> \
                    <div class='subdivs'> \
                        conteudo da subdiv \
                    </div> \
                    <div class='subdivs'> \
                        conteudo da subdiv \
                    </div> \
                </div>");
```

resultado: `"<div class='qualquer'>                     <div class='subdivs'>                         conteudo da subdiv                     </div>                     <div class='subdivs'>                         conteudo da subdiv                     </div>                 </div>"`

Ou você também pode dividir por linhas, e concatenar uma a uma usando carácter (`+`) conforme o exemplo a baixo:

```
variavel.append('<div class="qualquer">' +
                    '<div class="subdivs">' +
                        'conteudo da subdiv' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="subdivs">' +
                        'conteudo da subdiv' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>');
```

resultado: `"<div class="qualquer"><div class="subdivs">conteudo da subdiv</div><div class="subdivs">conteudo da subdiv</div></div>"`

A diferença entre os dois é que no primeiro insere semi-colunas no final de cada linha, já o segundo concatena diretamente. Lembrando que ambos pode ser adicionado a uma variável e você pode setar a mesma em seu `append()`.

Comment: Interessante. A solução é mais simples do que eu poderia imaginar!

Comment: editei o post explicando o problema, para um melhor intendimento :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o \n:

```
$('#teste').append('<div class="qualquer">\n<div class="subdivs">\nconteudo da subdiv\n</div>\n<div class="subdivs">\nconteudo da subdiv\n</div>\n</div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uv3nqemj/